# How to only return some map keys (aka, slice a range of map/set elements) in CQL 3?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I'm trying to do my own CF reverse index in Cassandra right now, for a geohash lookup implementation.

In CQL 2, I could do this:

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY song_tags (id uuid PRIMARY KEY) WITH comparator=text;
insert into song_tags ('id', 'blues', '1973') values ('a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4', '', '');
insert into song_tags ('id', 'covers', '2007') values ('8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469eb', '', '');
SELECT * FROM song_tags;
```

Which resulted in:

```
id,8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469eb | 2007, | covers,
id,a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4 | 1973, | blues,
```

And allowed to return 'covers' and 'blues' via:

```
SELECT 'a'..'f' FROM song_tags
```

Now, I'm trying to use CQL 3, which has gotten rid of dynamic columns, and suggests using a set or map column type instead.  sets and maps have their values/keys ordered alphabetically, and under the hood (iirc) are columns - hence, they should support the same type of range slicing...  but how?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to forget what you know about 'under the hood' implementation details and focus on what the query language lets you do.

Long reason why is in CQL3, multiple rows map to a single `columnfamily` though the query language presents them as different rows. It's just a different way of querying the same data.

Range slicing does not exist, the query language is flexible enough to support its use cases.

To do what you want, make an index on the genres so it is query-able without using the primary key and then select the genres value itself.

The 'gotcha' is that some functions can only be performed on partition keys, like `distinct`. Will have to do `distinct` client side in that case.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE song_tags (
           id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
           year text,
           genre list<text>
       );
CREATE INDEX ON song_tags(genre);
INSERT INTO song_tags (id, year, genre)
       VALUES(8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469eb, '2007', ['covers']);
INSERT INTO song_tags (id, year, genre)
       VALUES(a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4, '1973', ['blues']);
```

Can then query as:

```
SELECT genre from song_tags;

 genre
------------
  ['blues']
 ['covers']
```